# How to change colour of task bar

Tags: android

I want change the colour of the task bar i.e., The color of the very top of the line where the time and battery display etc. are located suppose to be dark gray instead of black. I have used

```
 setTitleColor(color.darker_gray);
```

But, It did not get effect. can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone know how to change colour of task bar

Comment: set windows background of your applicaiton to image of color your want This will autmaically change the status bar color

Answer (score 0):

your can use [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library :) it works only for kitkat + :)

**update:** the library name is : SystemBarTint in github.com

Comment: Thank you, Then what about below versions

Comment: this is github library :)

Answer (score 0):

**By Changing Theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
....
<!--Changing windowBackground will let your status change the color in most of the device-->
<item name="android:windowBackground">YOUR_COLOR</item>

...
</style>
```

**By Code**

```
  View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: Ok Thank you,But I have nine screens how do i change to backgrounds for nine screens

Comment: This is windows background not activity background if u want to change the color of status bar for each means You can create separate theme for all your screen and set those themes accordingly, else set it through code in your activity onCreateMethod. If you want one status bar color and different color for background of your activity means you can change it your layout file itself.
Best is to create theme in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You can define your custom theme for the app and set the action bar background there

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your app manifest file set the theme to MyTheme

Comment: he is asking for change the status bar not action bar, I think.